# How to use angular-cli source as global package?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to use the angular-cli source downloaded from the repo as the global package for all @angular and @angular-devkit packages. The [README](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/angular/cli/README.md#development-hints-for-working-on-angular-cli) for @angular/cli recommends running `yarn link` from dist/ and then `yarn link @angular/cli` for example from the project directory. However, the package files in angular-cli/dist do not contain a node_modules directory, so I get runtime errors when node loads packages w/ missing dependencies. Hope that makes sense.

My question is can anyone recommend a configuration that works so that I can use the angular-cli source as my global @angular and @angular-devkit package? Or is this just an error in angular-cli build, should npm build create package dependencies in angular-cli/dist?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: yeah @angular/cli is in npm's global package directory. i'm trying to make the angular-cli source downloaded from the repo my global packages as mentioned in the [README](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/angular/cli/README.md#development-hints-for-working-on-angular-cli). however, the configuration doesn't work b/c and node throws runtime errors.

Comment: have you tried deleting the node_modules folder and reinstalling npm?